# Crouton depends on libraries but is not a library itself

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, crouton

I'm using Android Studio 0.6.1, with [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) library and today after gradle sync I got next error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'project_name'.
Module version de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4 depends on libraries but is not a library itself
```

That's going on?

Comment: I've got, same error here. Trying to resolve.

Comment: Still having this issue on my end

Comment: @Revedko Please post your answer and accept it instead of editing your question.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This issue due to com.android.support-v4 recent update.

So I changed

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
```

and crouton works fine

Different workaround is to use @aar:

```
compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. How did you found this ?

Comment: @ChristopheSmet I knew about support-v4 recent update and first think was: hmmm, what is about downgrade it? Second solution I found on crouton github issues page :)

Comment: Currently Crouton still is a jar. The upcoming version will only be deployed as aar and use the `com.android.library` plugin.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately these solutions do not work for me, is there anything else I can do? Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'`

Comment: Second one is the general workaround for this problem :-) Thanks

Answer (score 7):

My solution according to @Revedko answer, using @aar and **change all supports to version lower than 21** -> 20.+

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.+'
    compile "com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.5"
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
}
```