# Error:Module version com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.3 depends on libraries but is not a library itself

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to apply material theme. After changing com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0 in build.gradle file to v7:21.0.0.-rc1 or v7:21+, i am getting following error:

> Module version com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.3 depends on
>   libraries but is not a library itself

com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.3 dependency is in another build.gradle which is like a project inside main project.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.3'
}
```

**Update:** I changed it to 1.4.4 but now I am getting:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugManifests'. Manifest
>   merging failed. See console for more info.

As per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962258/android-studio-gradle-manifest-merging-failed), I have 'android-L' everywhere, still no luck

Comment: any updates on this? How did you solve your error?

Answer (score 3):

By modifying the answer found here: [Crouton depends on libraries but is not a library itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450508/crouton-depends-on-libraries-but-is-not-a-library-itself)

I changed the dependency declaration in build.gradle as follows:

```
compile('com.strongloop:loopback-android:1.+@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

This seems to have solved it for me. If there is a better solution to this, I for one would like to hear what it is.