# Gradle Google Play Services gms module error

Tags: android, google-maps, module, gradle

I'm trying to build my Android Studio project with gradle. I added a compile rule as follows:

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

However it gives the following error:

```
Error:Module version com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87 depends on libraries but is not a library itself
```

I have tried changing version and excluding support-v4 module, as mentioned here:

[Crouton depends on libraries but is not a library itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450508/crouton-depends-on-libraries-but-is-not-a-library-itself)

But I cannot solve the error. 
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Here is my dependency list from my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    //    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.5') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your project a library project?

Comment: Nope, it is not a library project.

Comment: The problem occured when we changed the gms version from 6.1 to 6.5.87

Comment: please post your build.gradle

Comment: I'm using `play-services:6.5.87` without error. Have you tried cleaning your build?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have edited the question and added my dependency list.

Comment: @myanimal yeah, I have tried it many times but nothing changed.

Comment: I have also changed my operating system, switched to Ubuntu 14.04 from Windows 7, but I get the exact same error.

Comment: Are you using Jcenter or MavenCentral as your repository? Try Jcenter if you're using MaveCentral.

Comment: @myanimal I'm using jcenter as my repository.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Make sure you've updated everything in SDK manager. Also make sure in your gradle.build file that you're using the latest support libraries (appcompat-v7:21.0.3) and build tools version (21.1.2)

Comment: Me too. I have tried (appcompat-v7:21.0.3) and build tools version (21.1.2) but nothing changed.

Comment: I have tried sync my gradle with your dependencies, and pop up the error about three of com.comodo had the problem.

Comment: or you can try put  `publishNonDefault true` in android in your `build.gradle`, please refer to [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication)